# Should MySQL Table Rows create objects when queried in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I've worked for a long time with PHP, but I've never felt the need to use classes/objects. I've recently taken a break from PHP to focus on C++, where literally every new thing I make is a class.

I'm working on a new PHP project now and I wanted to give PHP OOP a shot. I'm currently designing a login/register system. Normally I would just query the database and use the resulting results directly for any output or manipulation that I might need.

However, I'm now wondering... Could it be better to convert the MySQL Results into a custom Account Object in PHP. Better yet.... Should I write custom DB Read & Write functions inside my classes so that when I need to save data to the database I just call something like...

```
$account.Save();
```

and to load a new account I would call something like...

```
$new_account = new Account(sql_result);
```

Or is it better that I stick to using the sql_results directly?

Comment: Why do you think OOP in PHP is that different from OOP in C++? In C++ you are fetching the result set in similar way. The implementation depends on the level of abstraction you want to achieve, i.e. how much you want to encapsulate into the account object.

Comment: Take a look at an ORM thats basically what you are taking about